# Android clickable links are too large (extend to the end of the line), and also wrap around

Tags: android

I have two lines of centered text that sits within a vertical linearLayout with bunch of other elements..

I have a link on 2 words, 1 of those words appear at the end of first line, and the second  word is at the beginning of the second line. The problem is the space from the end of first word to the right of the screen, and the space from the left of the screen to the second word is still clickable (the link space fully wraps around)

I have another link at the end of the second line, and that link extends all the way to the edge of the right screen as well..

How do i make sure that the clickable links for the texts are confined just to the texts and not on any spaces and so on?